# Needing to add user to all team projects at once

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have a user that will be auditing our team projects.We have 200+ projects and he needs access to all of them at stakeholder level.  how can I add this user to all team projects, without having to click through the web interface.  Can I script this out somehow?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add team members in Azure Devops via API? Also Groups API does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58916250/how-to-add-team-members-in-azure-devops-via-api-also-groups-api-does-not-work)

Comment: If you are using azure devops services, you can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser). When you add user to your organization, you have the option to add to projects, you can select add to all projects.